# Magento Error SQLSTATE[23000]: 1062 Duplicate entry log_visitor_info

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to setup a Magento website locally using MAMP, and I'm running into a recurring problem, each time I now try. Export the database using PHPMyAdmin (default config) and re-import PHPMyAdmin (default config) using MAMP 4.

I update site URLs, clear cache etc.

Everything appears to import correctly and work when i load the website for the first time. However, when I load any other page by either clicking a link or reloading the same page, i receive the following errors.

**Errors**

*XXXXXX = represents my local development path which has been removed for client privacy.*

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `log_visitor_info` (`visitor_id`, `http_referer`, `http_user_agent`, `http_accept_charset`, `http_accept_language`, `server_addr`, `remote_addr`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Trace:
#0 /XXXXXXX/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /XXXXXXX/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /XXXXXXX/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `na...', Array)
#4 /XXXXXXX/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `na...', Array)
#5 /XXXXXXX/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `na...', Array)
#6 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(203): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('l...', Array)
#7 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(129): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(198): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /XXXXXXX/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(69): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#18 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /XXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /XXXXXXX/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /XXXXXXX/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}

Error log record number: 1181609270934
```

**Things I've tried...**

1) Truncating visitor tables:

```
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
```

This fixes the problem for the initial page load only, once i visit another page, the same problem returns.

2) Disabling a local modules using app/etc/local.xml

3) Clearing cache, session data

**Other information:**

- Admin area is working correctly
- Magento ver. 1.9.2.4
- MAMP Version 4.0.6 (372)

**SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Feb 05, 2017 at 03:36 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.33
-- PHP Version: 5.6.27

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `XXXXXXX`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `log_visitor_info`
--

CREATE TABLE `log_visitor_info` (
`visitor_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
`http_referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Referrer',
`http_user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP User-Agent',
`http_accept_charset` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Charset',
`http_accept_language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Language',
`server_addr` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`remote_addr` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `log_visitor_info`
--

INSERT INTO `log_visitor_info` (`visitor_id`, `http_referer`,    `http_user_agent`, `http_accept_charset`, `http_accept_language`, `server_addr`,   `remote_addr`) VALUES
(0, NULL, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0', NULL, 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 0x7f000001, 0x7f000001);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `log_visitor_info`
--
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`);
```

Comment: Please use phpMyAdmin or some other MySQL client to issue the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE log_visitor_info;` on the system that's failing. That's the table identified by your error message.  Please [edit] your question to show us the complete definition of that table, *as it presently is on your server.*

Comment: Thanks O. Jones, I've edited my question. Is that the information you meant?

Comment: The `visitor_id` column is not rigged for `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Maybe somebody familiar with the magento schema knows whether it is intended that way.

Comment: I've had this before when exporting from MySQL if you export in compatibility mode, it doesn't export the `auto_increment` flags.  Either create them (there may be many) - or take a new export.

Comment: Thanks for your help Douglas. Yes this fixed problem. In order help others. I exported my DB dump using plesk (not phpMyAdmin) and then reimported with the settings `SQL Compatability = None` and `Do not use Auto-increment for Zero values = checked`

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue with my latest project and I solved it using the phpmyadmin to import the sql and set the compatibility to None and auto-increment for xero values to checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To solve my problem, I connected to phpmyadmin.

I selected the specified table in database and I used mysql tools "Analyse", "verify" and "repair".

This worked for me, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed

1. `auto-increment` is disabled on the `primary-key` of that table (log_visitor_info).
2. change `default` to `none` and `attributes` to `empty`